# How to send the csv file as file object using request module in python?

Tags: python, csv, file-upload, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file to particular website using request module in python, but the file which i am sending as a file object is not uploading

My code snippet is :

```
import requests
from requests import Session
import pdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import os
import subprocess
from pyexcel_xls import save_data
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
import urllib
import urllib2
def upload_file(user, password, file_object):
    login_data = {
            "utf8":"%E2%9C%93",
            "authenticity_token":"8vvZ+kWLuq+49LdzBeTQBGt78/HLwAf/MiKnWs2Jp0M=",
            "account[email]":user,
            "account[password]":password,
            "account[remember_me]":0,
            "account[remember_me]":1,
            "commit":"Sign in"
    }
    with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://www.mirraw.com/accounts/sign_in', data=login_data, headers={'connection':'keep-alive'})
    print p.status_code
    login_cookie = p.headers['set-cookie']
    upload_inventory = s.post('http://www.mirraw.com/designers/voylla/upload_csv', headers={'set-cookie':login_cookie}, files={'file':file_object})
    print upload_inventory.status_code

file_location = os.getcwd()
file_upload = file_location+"/upload_file.csv"
file_object = open(file_upload)
upload_file("user_name", "password", file_object)
```

Response I am getting as :
Status Code : 200 for p request
Status Code : 200 for upload_inventory request
But the file is uploaded or not it is not verified.
And Manually file is easily uploaded.
Please help me out where i am making mistake.

Comment: Can you please first fix your indentation?

Comment: Indentation fixed please help with your answer if you know.

Comment: Try openning the file in `rb` mode - `file_object = open(file_upload,'rb')` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar already tried but text response is same as previous.